# FileOutputStream issue with writing JSON from URL to internal storage

Tags: android, json, file-io

I'm having writing a JSON to file to be accessed, as to eliminate as much network access/delay from my app. I haven't dealt with writing files to memory before, and took the majority of the read/write code from Google's documentation, but I am still having issues.

Currently, I'm getting a null pointer exception at this line:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("runesInfo.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

This makes me believe that the file is never created, or that I am initializing it wrong, but I am not sure how.

The full code section:

```
public class GetRunes extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        boolean runesCached = false;

        protected String doInBackground(String[] runeId) {
            String url = "https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/" + region + "/v1.2/rune?api_key=" + api_key;
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject runeInfo = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            String jsonString = runeInfo.toString();
            String readJson = null;
            Context context = GetStaticData.this;

            if(!runesCached) {
                Log.d("Cache", "Caching File");

                try {
                    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "runesInfo.json");
                    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("runesInfo.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fOut.write(jsonString.getBytes());
                    fOut.close();
                    Log.d("Cache", "Cache Complete");
                    runesCached = true;

                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            String name = null;
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("runesInfo.json");
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);

                fis.read(readJson.getBytes());
                JSONObject storedJson = new JSONObject(readJson);
                Log.d("Stored JSON", "" + storedJson);
                JSONObject idJson = storedJson.getJSONObject("data");
                JSONObject single = idJson.getJSONObject(runeId[0]);


                try {
                    name = single.getString("name");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return name;
        }
    }
```

Logcat:

```
04-29 09:53:58.199  11273-11732/edu.appdesign.leaguestats D/Cache﹕ Caching File
04-29 09:53:58.199  11273-11732/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 09:53:58.199  11273-11732/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContextWrapper.getFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java)
04-29 09:53:58.199  11273-11732/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData$GetRunes.doInBackground(GetSt
04-29 09:53:58.199  11273-11732/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData$GetRunes.doInBackground(GetSt
04-29 09:53:58.199  11273-11732/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java)
04-29 09:53:58.199  11273-11732/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
04-29 09:53:58.199  11273-11732/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java)
04-29 09:53:58.209  11273-11732/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
04-29 09:53:58.209  11273-11732/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
04-29 09:53:58.209  11273-11732/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
04-29 09:53:58.209  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 09:53:58.209  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java)
04-29 09:53:58.209  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java)
04-29 09:53:58.209  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java)
04-29 09:53:58.209  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData.getRuneInfo(GetStaticData.jav
04-29 09:53:58.209  11273-11732/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=20: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41650e18)
04-29 09:53:58.209  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.RunesActivity$GetRunes.onPostExecute(RunesA
04-29 09:53:58.219  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.RunesActivity$GetRunes.onPostExecute(RunesA
04-29 09:53:58.219  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java)
04-29 09:53:58.219  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java)
04-29 09:53:58.219  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java)
04-29 09:53:58.219  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
04-29 09:53:58.219  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
04-29 09:53:58.219  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
04-29 09:53:58.219  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

04-29 09:53:58.219  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
04-29 09:53:58.219  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit
04-29 09:53:58.219  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
04-29 09:53:58.229  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:133)
04-29 09:53:58.229  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 09:53:58.229  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 09:53:58.229  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java)
04-29 09:53:58.229  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData$GetRunes.doInBackground(GetSt
04-29 09:53:58.229  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at edu.appdesign.leaguestats.GetStaticData$GetRunes.doInBackground(GetSt
04-29 09:53:58.229  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java)
04-29 09:53:58.229  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
04-29 09:53:58.229  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java)
04-29 09:53:58.229  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
04-29 09:53:58.239  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
04-29 09:53:58.239  11273-11273/edu.appdesign.leaguestats W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
```

Comment: Please share the logcat.

Comment: @ManishMulimani Relevant logcat section added

Comment: I think, it may be because of wrong context. Is GetRunes inner class? openFileOutput is a method of a Context(most probably Activity). It may be null in your code, as doInBackground executed in separate thread. So, try to add "context." to it and check if it is not null. Btw, try to avoid holding context in static variable.

Comment: @Olsavage GetRunes is a class within a GetStaticData class, which is called by my activity RunesActivity. Does this mean I should be using RunesActivity for the context? To clarify, there are 2 files, GetStaticData, which contains GetRunes, and RunesActivity.

Comment: You should use openFileOutput with not null context. It may be RunesActivity, if it will be already created and not finished. What GetStaticData extends?

Comment: @Olsavage Just Activity. I'm just really using it as a file to hold a bunch of my methods to, as the name would imply, fetch static data from a server and pass it back to be displayed.

Comment: @Nate, so that your issue, you use method with not existing context.

Comment: @Olsavage How would I resolve this issue?

Comment: @Olsavage Another strange thing is that I have other methods in this configuration and they work just fine, but this one doesn't. Why would some work but others not?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use android [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). I think, it will fit the best for your need. Just move your code to Service, get rid of static context, execute your AsyncTask at onStartCommand method and call startService, when you need to save JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "runesInfo.json");
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("runesInfo.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You create a file instance, but never use it in the stream.

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(context.getFilesDir(), "runesInfo.json"));
```

Should do the job.